# Calling custom AuthenticationHandler from Faces bean throws IllegalStateException: Cannot change buffer size after data has been written

Tags: jsf, spring-security

What would be the correct way to call custom AuthenticationHandler from with in jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped?

The following code throws below exception

```
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@Component
@ViewScoped
public class TotpVerifyView implements Serializable {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public void verify() throws Exception 
    {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        TotpAuthenticationHandler totpAuthenticationHandler = appContext.getBean(TotpAuthenticationHandler.class);

        totpAuthenticationHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class TotpAuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler, Serializable {

    public TotpAuthenticationHandler(String thirdAuthUrl) 
    {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler(thirdAuthUrl);
        successHandler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
        this.thirdSuccessHandler = successHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        thirdSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

}
```

```
    @Bean
    TotpAuthenticationHandler totpAuthenticationHandler()
    {
        return new TotpAuthenticationHandler("/verify-bla");
    }
```

Complete stack trace:

```
27-Mar-2024 15:22:53,382 [35mERROR[0;39m [32m[http-nio-8080-exec-10][0;39m [34m[org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter:164][0;39m - [05f30253-2dcc-4832-83f4-72a4089b87f3][127.0.0.1] FacesExceptionFilter: An exception occurred during processing servlet request. Error page '/error/error.jsf' will be shown.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change buffer size after data has been written
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.checkCommitted(ResponseFacade.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:226) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:721) ~[myfaces-impl-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextWrapper.java:437) ~[myfaces-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextWrapper.java:437) ~[myfaces-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2105) ~[myfaces-impl-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1751) ~[myfaces-impl-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:316) ~[myfaces-impl-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:74) ~[myfaces-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:74) ~[myfaces-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:74) ~[myfaces-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:166) ~[omnifaces-4.3.jar:4.3]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:122) ~[myfaces-impl-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241) ~[myfaces-impl-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:225) ~[myfaces-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:118) ~[omnifaces-4.3.jar:4.3]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108) ~[omnifaces-4.3.jar:4.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:479) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:340) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:128) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at  org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at com.synaptic.core.filter.CustomWhitelistFilter.doFilter(CustomWhitelistFilter.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:151) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:129) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at com.synaptic.core.filter.CustomSessionFilter.doFilter(CustomSessionFilter.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226) ~[rewrite-servlet-10.0.2.Final.jar:10.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your custom `AuthenticationHandler` has already written to the response. It is probably sending a forward or redirect to a different page all by itself.

In that case you'll need to inform Faces that the response is complete.

```java
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

This way Faces won't touch the response during render response phase. Because the default behavior is to redisplay/render the same page from where the Faces action was invoked.