Upgrade to Jakarta Faces 4.0: IllegalStateException after successfull basic authentication
I'm trying to upgrade a legacy spring boot + Primefaces web application.
After successful authentication (it's basic authentication on my local machine, LDAP in production) I get an java.lang.IllegalStateException. Here is the relevant part of the stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change buffer size after data has been written
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.checkCommitted(ResponseFacade.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.setBufferSize(ResponseFacade.java:226)
        at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
        at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
        at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
        at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
        at jakarta.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.setBufferSize(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextImpl.java:871)
        at jakarta.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.setResponseBufferSize(ExternalContextWrapper.java:932)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:892)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:392)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:163)
        at jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:125)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:93)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:178)
        at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:692)
        at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at my.package.WebSecurityFilter.doFilter(WebSecurityFilter.java:82)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at my.package.WebSecurityRequestFilter.doFilter(WebSecurityRequestFilter.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
...

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78237291 I have to call FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete(); to prevent Faces touching response. But I can't figure out where to put this code in the chain because faces context is not created before call to jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp).
Here is my web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="6.0" id = "WebApp_ID" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd">
    <display-name>vikthor</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>start.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config/>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <display-name>LoggingConfigurationServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>LoggingConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.LoggingConfigurationServlet</servlet-class>
        <multipart-config/>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoggingConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/log</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- TODO remove this filter when no h:inputText components are used-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
        <!--suppress WebProperties -->
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>webSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>my.package.WebSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>webSecurityRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>my.package.WebSecurityRequestFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>webSecurityRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>webSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Define the state method to be used. There are two different options
            defined by the specification: 'client' and 'server' state.
        </description>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security.taglib.xml;/WEB-INF/myAppComponents.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/forbidden.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>my.package.IllegalGetParameterException</exception-type>
        <location>/error-getparameter.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>native</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>
            jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
        </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>


I would start by looking at this code my.package.WebSecurityFilter.doFilter your filter is the only non standard class in the chain and could possibly be doing something it should not be?
